# How to align centre the title whilst keeping logo left in the header?

Tags: header-footer, logos

Need help to align the logo left but keep the title centred. Atm, the two move together or are removed with any edits to the preamble I have tried.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}% http://ctan.org/pkg/braket
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor  = blue, citecolor = blue, anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\twodigit{\THEDAY}{ }\shortmonthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=1em\indent}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\usepackage{titling}


\pretitle{%
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=2cm]{image.png}\\[\bigskipamount]
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE}
}
\posttitle{\end{flushleft}}


\date{\today}

\title{Financial Analysis}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}% http://ctan.org/pkg/braket
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor = blue, citecolor = blue, anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\twodigit{\THEDAY}{ }\shortmonthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=1em\indent}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\usepackage{titling}


\pretitle{%
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{suitcase1}\end{flushleft}\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}}


\date{\today}

\title{Financial Analysis}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the example could be stripped down some, but, if I understand what you are looking for, this is one way to do it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, % to help visualize the output
a4paper, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}% 
\usepackage{mwe}% for `example-image-a`
\usepackage{titling}

\newlength\imgwd
\newlength\imght
\newcommand{\setimg}[3]{%
  % #1 = filename | #2 = width | #3 = height
  \def\imgname{#1}
  \setlength{\imgwd}{#2}
  \setlength{\imght}{#3}
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \insertimg
  \vspace*{\dimexpr -\imght -1.2\baselineskip \relax}%
  {\pretitle \thetitle \posttitle}%
  \begin{center}
  {\preauthor \theauthor \postauthor}%
  \par
  {\predate \thedate \postdate}%
  \end{center}
}

\newcommand\insertimg{%
  \par\noindent
  \includegraphics[width=\imgwd,height=\imght]{\imgname}}

\renewcommand{\pretitle}{\par\LARGE\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand{\posttitle}{\par}
\renewcommand{\preauthor}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\postauthor}{}
\renewcommand{\predate}{}
\renewcommand{\postdate}{}

\setimg{example-image-a}{7cm}{2cm}
\title{Financial Analysis}
\author{Karl Polanyi}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

% For comparison
\bigskip

\begin{center}
{\LARGE\bfseries \thetitle}

\theauthor

\thedate
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The main addition is the `\setimg` command, which allows you to specify the image and dimensions at the same time you provide all the other document 'metadata'.  (I also used the `titling` packages `\pre`-/`\post`-commands, but there is no real advantage to do so when the `\maketitle` command is redefined ... beyond, I suppose, the fact that the those command names are quite sensible ones.)